# Targeting text area or input using css for valid invalid in css

Tags: html, css

I have valid and invalid attributes for my input areas but for my retype password i am using js to match the password, the input stays red, i just want to target that input/textarea and give my own colors, i have tried this code but it changes all the input areas and not the retype input.

```
input:focus:invalid,
textarea:focus:invalid[required][name="retypepassword"] {
    border:2px solid green;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px #F5192F;
    color:blue;
}
```

This my actual css:

```
textarea:focus, input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

input:focus:invalid,
textarea:focus:invalid {
    border:2px solid #F5192F;
    box-shadow:0 0 4px #F5192F;
    color:red;
}

input:focus:valid,
textarea:focus:valid {
    border: 2px solid #09c;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #09c;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to target the retype password input and textarea ?
i have this line of code which is probably overriding it?

```
   input[required]:invalid {
    background: #efdee0 url(../images/invalid.png) no-repeat center 
    right;
    }

    input[required]:valid {
    background: hsla(235, 100%, 96%, 1) url(../images/valid.png)    
    no-repeat center right;
```

}

Comment: Please show your HTML code, and maybe your JS too ? Use a web snippet if you can.

Comment: Maybe the problem in your js code, - as far as you saying it stays red only for the input you manipulating with javascript? Also consider creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/39eLw3e0/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/50e213yk/

Comment: strange on the js fiddle the retype changes to blue but on my site it stays red therefore i wanted to give it my own colors.

Comment: no that jsfiddle you gave did not do it

Comment: if i remove the js and then type retype password it does change to blue at valid but with the js it stays red.

Answer (score 0):

The js is causing the input not to validate and change to valid, therefore changed to the following code which worked:

```
 $().ready(function(){
$("#registration").validate({
    rules: { 
        pswd: {
            required: true
        },
        retypepassword: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#pswd"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        pswd: "Please enter password",
        retypepassword: "Please enter valid confirm password"
    },      
    submitHandler: function() { $('#registration').submit(); }
     });
    });
```

Initially i wanted to target the retype input because the validation was not working so i can change it to a neutral color and not add validation on the retype.